# Inflating a view Dynamically in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I am pretty new to DataBinding and unable to figure out to how to inflate a view Dynamically in MVVM

More Specifically,the requirement is to inflate a Layout with a 2 TextViews onClick of the Add button and remove that View onClick of Delete Button.

Without MVVM things are seem simple enough but with MVVM can someone help me on how to accomplish the same.

Comment: Did you get any solution using MVVM?

Answer (score -1):

This example uses Kotlin as the main language.

Enable databinding in your gradle (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    // LiveData + ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    ...
}
```

Now create three files like:

- TestViewModel //It will contain the models that will nourish information to the View (test_fragment_layout)
- TestFragment //It will contain an instance of TestViewModel and FragmentTestBinding (autogenerated class)
- layout_test_fragment.xml //FragmentTest's layout

Now add two strings to TestViewModel ...

```
class TestViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var textA: String? = null
    private var textB: String? = null

    fun setUp(textA: String, textB: String) {
        this.textA = textA
        this.textB = textB
    }

    //Kotlin needs explicit getters, used by autogenerated class
    fun getTextA() = textA 
    fun getTextB() = textB
}
```

Now create a TestFragment and its layout_test_fragment.xml

The layout will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.test.viewmodel.TestViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".TestFragment">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.textA}" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.textB}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Having the layout, compile your project and AndroidStudio will create a class called FragmentTestBinding (location: app> build> generated> source> apt> debug> com.yourpackage> FragmentTestBinding)

Finally, in TestFragment add the following lines

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.setUp("Hello World", "from DataBinding")
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

And voilà, this is the
  [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wepOA.png).

I uploaded the example to [github](https://github.com/jclemus91/MVVMTest), greetings

Comment: the question was about inflating a layout dynamically. In your example, there is no mention of it.